# SpaCy v3 Textcat is not updating through iterations

Tags: python, spacy-3

I'm trying to train a custom text categorizer with SpaCy v3. However the textcat model does not seem to be updating through iterations. In fact losses are exactly the same. Here is the training part of my code:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')

config = {
    "threshold": 0.5,
}

textcat = nlp.add_pipe("textcat", config=config, last=True)
for label in binarizer.classes_:
    textcat.add_label(str(label))

optimizer = nlp.initialize()

for i in range(50):
    random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
    losses = {}
    for batch in minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=16):
        textcat.update(batch, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
    print(i, losses)
```

TRAIN_DATA is a list of examples.

Thanks

Comment: This was answered on the spaCy forums, but basically with the Transformer model training needs extra steps. In general it's recommended you follow the instructions in the docs on config-based training because it's easy to make mistakes with custom training loops. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/9019

Comment: @polm23 Yes. I could manage to solve the problem with that answer. Everything seems to be fine now. Thanks.